# Merging all trello boards calendars

Tags: trello, google-calendar

Is there some possibility to merge all boards calendars from one account to Google Calendar? And not by adding them one by one (I want to use it on 100+ boards)...

Answer (score 2):

I use Sunrise (http://sunrise.am), which can aggregate calendars including Google and Trello into one calendar.  It does not put the Trello information in the Google calendar, though.

The Trello integration is 2-way and continuous -- so if you move the event in Sunrise, the card will get a new due date.

Comment: Came to suggest Sunrise as well. Great app, works like a charm with Trello.